# Xdotool - key pressing at intervals

Tags: xdotool

I would like the F6 button to be pressed every 20 minutes in the game. I have xdotool but i dont know how to used it. I have Linux Mint.

I know now:

while sleep 1200; do

xdotool key F6

done

This is answer

Comment: Add you answer as an answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

A search for "bash continuous loop" will quickly learn you how to have a loop that runs forever. Them you include the `sleep 2000` command in the loop before the `xdotool key F6` command.

Such loop will run forever, so have the 20 minutes pauze, then simulate hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>. To get out of the loop, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal where you started the command.

Comment: Thank you and 20 minutes is sleep 1200

Comment: Have this command a limit ? because I havent spotted.

Comment: I mean xdotool key F6 command